# Building a list from user input throughout different functions

Tags: python, python-2.7

I started the how to learn python the hard way recently. I'm on exercise 36, where we design our own text adventure game. I was hoping to have the user go through different rooms collecting items to later be used on the boss in the last room. But I can't figure our how to keep adding to the same list when I change rooms. This is what i have so far for that part (I cut out description text)...

```
def add_item():
    backpack = []
    i = 0
    while 1:
        i += 1
        item = raw_input(" > ")
        if item == '':
            break
        backpack.append(item)

        print "\nAh, the %s, let us hope this serves you well." % item
        print "This is the inventory you have acquired so far..."
        print backpack

def dizzygas_hallway():
    print "If so which item do you choose? (cloak or pendant)"
    add_item()

def dark_laboratory():
    print "Which item do you take? (book, potion or sword)\n"
    add_item()
    print "You exit the only door in sight..."
dizzygas_hallway()
```

Comment: FWIW, the SO Python Chat room regulars [do not recommend LPTHW](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints). If it's working for you, that's great, but please be aware that there are several problems with this book. Also be aware that Python 2 will reach its End Of Life in 2020, so you really ought to be learning Python 3, unless you need Python 2 to work on legacy code.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Very much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think you're close, just swap some lines around. Otherwise every time you wanted to add an item, you create an new, empty list.

```
backpack = []  # Define outside of function

def add_item():
    global backpack  # Use global variable (this line isn't 'necessary', though)
```

Comment: You don't need `global` here since you're only mutating `backpack`, not assigning to it.

Comment: True. Doesn't hurt, though, to explain that it's possible

Comment: Hmmm. I try to avoid using `global` directives. I guess it does alert the reader that you're modifying a global, but when I see a `global` statement I naturally assume an assignment is being made, and if I _don't_ see one I assume there's a bug. :)